# range out of order in character class in regex jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jquery validator plugin to test a regEx and display an error message when the regex is not matched. Take a look at the code that I have written so far.

```
<form name="sampleForm" id="sampleForm" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" required/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" style="margin-top:10px;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also take a look at the js code that I have written below :

```
<script>
  $().ready(function() {
    $('#sampleForm').validate({
      rules: {
        phoneNumber: {
          required: true,
          nameTest: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        phoneNumber: {
          required: "Please enter anything"
        }
      }
    });
  });
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("nameTest", function(value, element) {
    return /^[a-Z]$/.test(value);
  }, "success, it's working");
</script>
```

I just used a simple regEx to allow only a-z alphabets with `/^[a-Z]$/`.

I don't know why but I'm getting :

> Invalid regular expression: /^[a-Z]$/: Range out of order in character class

Please help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because `a` (97) is after `Z` (90) in the ASCII encoding sequence -  so the range is out of order:

```js
console.log('a'.charCodeAt(0));
console.log('Z'.charCodeAt(0));
```

So this would be valid (but not intuitive):

```
/^[Z-a]$/
```

You should use this regex to match letters A to Z for both upper and lower case:

```
/^[A-Za-z]$/
```

Comment: Awesome, it's working :)